# Delete k8s namespace - possibility to recover

Tags: kubernetes

If we deleted a NS which was actually stuck without deletion due to finalizer configuration is it possible to cancel the execution and get the NS back to Active ?

example

spec:

finalizers:

- **kubernetes**

status:

phase: **Terminating**

Comment: AFAIK a namespace deletion may take some time but once it's finished, all resources inside of it is deleted and there is no possibility to recover it, unless you have any backup created. Do you have any?  Is there anything left if in this namespace if you check with `kubectl get all -n name_of_the_namespace`?

Comment: Well after struggling a lot.. we found a way to handle this... here's the fix.. patch the NS and remove the finaliser : Kubernetes , then immediately create back the NS... this will put the namespace back as active as it was.. all the PODs, PVC, SVCs were retained without any issue... Don't know why but it restored the NS back..

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it, consider writing and accepting your own answer, so if someone from community will have the same issue he will find the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Well after struggling a lot.. we found a way to handle this... here's the fix.. patch the NS and remove the **finalizer : Kubernetes** , then immediately create back the NS... this will put the namespace back as active as it was.. all the PODs, PVC, SVCs were retained without any issue... Don't know why but it restored the NS back.